# Mapping object from sibling node in json in RestKit

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

JSON

```
{
   "entity": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name"
   },
   "settings": {
      "key": "value"
   }
}
```

**Entity Model**

Attributes: id, name

Relationship: settings(one to one)

**Settings Model**

Attributes: key

Relationship: entity(reverse relationship, one to one)

EntityMapping

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
mapping.persistentStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.firstObject;

mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id" : @"id",
                                              @"name" : @"name"
                                              }];
```

Had settings been inside entity in json response, I would add this

```
[mapping addPropertyMapping:
    [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"settings" 
      toKeyPath:@"settings" withMapping:[Settings map]]
];
```

But my response id different than this, so how should I map correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Both `entity` and `settings` are in a container dictionary, so you can change your response descriptor to not drill down so far and then use key paths to drill into the `entity` part and have direct access to the `settings` part:

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                          @"entity.id" : @"id",
                                          @"entity.name" : @"name"
                                          }];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"settings" toKeyPath:@"settings" withMapping:[Settings map]]];
```